# save the object's state during screen rotation

Tags: android, object, screen-orientation

i have two objects for mediaplayer mp and mp1.
Both objects save the state of the media player.Here is the code

```
        public  Object  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() 
              {
            HashMap<String,Object> player = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            MediaPlayer instance = mp;
            player.put("mp", instance);
            mp = null;
            MediaPlayer instance1 = mp1;
            player.put("mp1", instance1);
            mp1 = null;
            return player;

        }
```

this is my prob:
State of mp1 is saved.That is when i rotate the screen,the instance of mp1 continues from where it was.
Whereas mp restarts when i rotate the screen.Help me out please

Answer (score 0):

For a MediaPlayer, you should really consider handling its state in a service and not in an activity : 
its lifecycle is very different from the one of your activity (for example you may want to keep playing sounds when the user leave the app) and it has nothing to do in the UI thread.
It would also save the configuration changes handling.